# How to convert a List<MyEntity> myEntities = Arrays.asList(/** MyEntity[] **/); to JSON data and send via Post to Node

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, node.js

I have a generic list of custom Objects I pulled from a database:

```
List<MyEntity> myEntities = Arrays.asList(/** MyEntity[] **/);
```

I try to send convert this to JSON and send to a server where Node is listening, but it fails.

**The list converted to JSON looks like:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "_myEntityAccessPermission": 0,
    "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntityGUID": 119,
    "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySubType": "my_user_entity",
    "_myEntityType": "my_user_entity",
    "_timeCreated": "Thu Aug 16 08:56:02 2018\n",
    "_timeUpdated": "Thu Aug 16 08:56:02 2018\n",
    "myUserEntity": {
      "_email": "TryMyilo@Yahoo.com",
      "_fullNames": "Oliver ",
      "_sessionCode": 0,
      "_id": 0,
      "_myEntityAccessPermission": -1,
      "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "_myEntityAccessPermission": 0,
    "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntityGUID": 120,
    "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySubType": "my_user_entity",
    "_myEntityType": "my_user_entity",
    "_timeCreated": "Thu Aug 16 11:44:24 2018\n",
    "_timeUpdated": "Thu Aug 16 11:44:24 2018\n",
    "myUserEntity": {
      "_email": "Eddy",
      "_fullNames": "Eddy Koma Myilo Oliver",
      "_sessionCode": 0,
      "_id": 0,
      "_myEntityAccessPermission": -1,
      "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "_myEntityAccessPermission": 0,
    "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntityGUID": 121,
    "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySubType": "my_user_entity",
    "_myEntityType": "my_user_entity",
    "_timeCreated": "Thu Aug 16 11:45:18 2018\n",
    "_timeUpdated": "Thu Aug 16 11:45:18 2018\n",
    "myUserEntity": {
      "_email": "Kim",
      "_fullNames": "Kim",
      "_sessionCode": 0,
      "_id": 0,
      "_myEntityAccessPermission": -1,
      "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "_myEntityAccessPermission": 0,
    "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntityGUID": 122,
    "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySubType": "my_user_entity",
    "_myEntityType": "my_user_entity",
    "_timeCreated": "Thu Aug 16 15:40:05 2018\n",
    "_timeUpdated": "Thu Aug 16 15:40:05 2018\n",
    "myUserEntity": {
      "_email": "Fam",
      "_fullNames": "Eddy Oliver Maurice Esther Ann George Paul ",
      "_sessionCode": 0,
      "_id": 0,
      "_myEntityAccessPermission": -1,
      "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 0,
    "_myEntityAccessPermission": 0,
    "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntityGUID": 123,
    "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1,
    "_myEntitySubType": "my_user_entity",
    "_myEntityType": "my_user_entity",
    "_timeCreated": "Fri Aug 17 02:20:25 2018\n",
    "_timeUpdated": "Fri Aug 17 02:20:25 2018\n",
    "myUserEntity": {
      "_email": "Dan",
      "_fullNames": "Dan ",
      "_sessionCode": 0,
      "_id": 0,
      "_myEntityAccessPermission": -1,
      "_myEntityContainerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityGUID": -1,
      "_myEntityOwnerGUID": -1,
      "_myEntitySiteGUID": -1
    }
  }
]
```

**This is the method that I am trying to make work**

```
  private void sendPost() {
    String postURL = "http://192.168.100.11:3000/sound";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    JSONArray array=new JSONArray();

    List<MyEntity> myEntities = Arrays.asList(new MyPersLibRead().myPersGetALLMyEntityUnSyched());

    for (MyEntity myEntity : myEntities) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(myEntity);

        try {
            array.put(new JSONObject(json));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.v("MyApp", json);
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("filter",array);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.v("MyApp",">>>>>>>>> " +  array.toString());

    JsonObjectRequest jobReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, postURL, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                    Log.v("MyApp", jsonObject.toString());

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    Log.v("MyApp", "ERR >>>");

                }
            });

    queue.add(jobReq);
}
```

**On the Node side:**

```
// This responds a POST request
app.post('/sound', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Got a POST request");

    console.log(req);

    res.send(req);
});
```

**The error thrown by Node:**

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at /var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/app.js:39:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /var/www/html/node/my_node_pers_remote/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

How can I successfully send this data to Node via JSON?

Comment: The problem appears to be on the Node side, not the Java side.  I do not have the expertise in Node to tell you what you *should* do, but I would not expect sending the whole request object as a response to be appropriate.  Perhaps you want to extract the request body (i.e the message payload) and echo *that* back, but that, I would think, is only one part of the overall request object.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Gson. That will help you covert your list to Json string

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
 // convert your list to json
 String jsonCartList = gson.toJson(cartList);
 // print your generated json
 System.out.println("jsonCartList: " + jsonCartList);
```

Comment: The OP already successfully converts his list to JSON, or so it seems.  He presents the result in the question.  If "Simply use GSON" is in fact a solution to the problem, then this answer would be much improved by explaining what difference that should be expected to make, and / or what is wrong with the JSON that the OP is already obtaining.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @alex. How can I iterate the post request and get the individual JSON objects in the JSON object Array? That is on the Node side.